# Is Loading Images From HTTP on a HTTPS Website Dangerous?

Tags: http, security, ssl, browser, https

Chrome grays out the green lock of a HTTPS website when the site is trying to load scripts or images from insecure sources.

I understand that scripts from insecure connection may be hacked to change the website content or steal user data. But why does loading insecure images a problem as well?

Does a .jpg or .png file from the HTTP protocol really may cause any security issues?